# Ask about c# Deserialize

Tags: c#, deserialization

I got a XML :

```
<g1:Person xmlns:g1="http://api.google.com/staticInfo/">
  <g1:Id> 005008</g1:Id>
    <g1:age>23></g1:age>
    </g1:Person>
```

How to deserialize it to Person Object.

I just find a way .

```
  XmlDocument xdc = new XmlDocument();
                xdc.Load(xmlpath);

                xdc.LoadXml(xdc.InnerXml.Replace("g1:",""));

                xdc.Save(xmlpath);
```

Any other ways to make it easy. or a advanced method  with it.

```
        xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
        XmlDocument xdc = new XmlDocument();
        xdc.Load(xmlpath);

        xdc.LoadXml(xdc.InnerXml.Replace("g1:",""));

        xdc.Save(xmlpath);


      Stream  stm = new FileStream(xmlpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

   Person p= xs.Deserialize(stm) as Person;
```

Comment: The posted code doesn't deserialize. Can you post your actual code?

Comment: Just so you know, that prefix section is called a [Namespace Prefix](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp), and to add on to  @Oded's request, can you include more of the XML file, specifically the top of the file.

Comment: I added the completed  code .Any ways to make it easy without replacing?

Comment: Define "easy". What do you find to be a problem?

Comment: actually I got a HotelAPI that provides xml like this.  and I need to load and read to deserialize it. but there are many "g1:" in the xml prefix.  I need to replace it and save it .that's so complex. I want a solution to make it easy

Comment: You don't need to replace it at all. You just need to add the namespace, or start using `XDocument` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class and specify the namespace for the [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) and [XmlRoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx) attributes:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

...

// TODO: Move the namespace name to a const variable
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Person", Namespace = "http://api.google.com/staticInfo/")]
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Id", Namespace="http://api.google.com/staticInfo/")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "age", Namespace = "http://api.google.com/staticInfo/")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

...

string input =
    @"<g1:Person xmlns:g1=""http://api.google.com/staticInfo/"">
        <g1:Id>005008</g1:Id>
        <g1:age>23</g1:age>
      </g1:Person>";

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
Person person = (Person)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(input));
```

Alternatively, the default namespace can be specified in the constructor of XmlSerializer and the Namespace property left unspecified:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person), 
    "http://api.google.com/staticInfo/");
```

To ensure the namespace prefix is "q1", specify the [XmlSerializerNamespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces.aspx) to use. For example:

```
Person person; // Assuming it is populated as above
using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, person, 
        new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new [] { new XmlQualifiedName("q1", "http://api.google.com/staticInfo/") }));
    memoryStream.Flush();
    Console.Out.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(memoryStream.GetBuffer()));
}
```

It shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<q1:Person xmlns:q1="http://api.google.com/staticInfo/">
  <q1:Id>5008</q1:Id>
  <q1:age>23</q1:age>
</q1:Person>
```

Comment: I have removed the string namespace declaration and the above code works on VS 2012.

Comment: Message=<Person xmlns='http://api.google.com/staticInfo/'> was not expected.   error again.

Comment: Are you using my Person class definition or yours? I get the same error if I remove the Namespace argument to the XmlRoot attribute of the Person class. I.e. `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Person")] public class Person ...`

Comment: Oh,it works fine now . I lost the xmlRoot . Thank you man. Can I ask u  how to   serialize Person with  'g1:'  prefix.   I know the deserialize. may be someday I would serialize some objects like this xml.